# Input string was not in a correct format. (Editable Gridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Whenever I try to edit information inside my gridview it throws me this error....

here is my code for row editing

```
protected void GRDTech_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{  
 GRDTech.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
 GRDTech.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
 BindData();
}
```

and here is my code:

```
 bool comparedResults = true;
TextBox txtAddFROMKMREAD = (TextBox)Default._def.GRDTech
    .FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddFROMKMREAD");
DropDownList drpPlateNum = (DropDownList)Default._def.GRDTech
    .FooterRow.FindControl("drpPlateNum");
string txt = txtAddFROMKMREAD.Text;
int readDepartureKM = Convert.ToInt32(txtAddFROMKMREAD.Text);

TextBox txtAddTOKMREADING = (TextBox)Default._def
    .GRDTech.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddTOKMREADING");

int arrivalKMreading = Convert.ToInt32(txtAddTOKMREADING.Text);

comparedResults = (arrivalKMreading < readDepartureKM);
```

the part `int readDepartureKM` keeps on giving me an error that the input string is incorrect. how do I fix this?

Comment: Well what value are you trying to parse? Presumably it's not a valid integer...

Comment: the value inside my textbox, in my database, the datatype is int I don't know why it is giving me that error

Comment: Perhaps the value hasn't actually made it to the control properly? Or perhaps it's a NULL value in the database? You should either add logging or step through in a debugger to find the string which you're trying to parse.

Comment: have you checked whether `txtAddFROMKMREAD` is null? This must be the case here. Also curious, what is `FooterRow` doing on an edit? Don't you have an `EditItemTemplate`? Please show your `GridView` markup too.

Comment: it has a value inside my database.

Comment: @user3487415 Debug your code and tell us what is the value of your `txtAddFROMKMREAD.Text` and your `CurrentCulture` exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the value you have in `txtAddTOKMREADING.Text` is not a vlid `integer` (might be blank?).

When you are not sure the text is valid (for example, when you use a `textbox` for an input from the user), It is better to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

From the documentation of `int.TryParse`:

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

```
int readDepartureKM ;
bool parsedSuccessfully = int.TryParse(txtAddFROMKMREAD.Text, out readDepartureKM )
if(parsedSuccessfully)
{
    //Do something with the value that is in readDepartureKM 
}
else
{
   //do something else (perhaps an error message?)
   string message =String.Format("'{0}' Is not a valid integer.",txtAddFROMKMREAD.Text);
}
```

Comment: I used this code and I assigned a message box, an error is prompted, but also allows me to edit, so more or less I would be using this one..